# Why does memoize function in D. Flanagan's "JS: Definitive Guide" need arguments.length?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, memoization, higher-order-functions

I'm going through David Flanagan's "Javascript: The Definitive Guide".

In paragraph 8.8.4 he shows a higher-order function, `memoize()` that accepts a function as its argument and returns a memoized version of the function:

```
 //Return a memoized version of f.
// It only works if arguments to f all have distinct string representations.
 function memoize(f) {
      var cache = {}; // Value cache stored in the closure.

      return function() {
          // Create a string version of the arguments to use as a cache key.
          var key = arguments.length + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,",");
          if (key in cache) return cache[key];
          else return cache[key] = f.apply(this, arguments);
      }
 }
```

In the explanation there is: "The returned function **converts its arguments array to a string**".

If we only need the arguments, why does he concatenate `arguments.length` with `Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ",")` instead of only converting arguments array to a string?

Comment: because it is used later to access cache of calls. And there is a difference if you call method with different number of parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because otherwise this two calls would be stored with the same key:

```
memoizedFunc('', '');
memoizedFunc(',');
```

In both cases joining arguments results with the same string: `,`

Answer (score 1):

This function is broken. It doesn't work even when all the arguments are strings. See this example:

```js
 //Return a memoized version of f.
// It only works if arguments to f all have distinct string representations.
 function memoize(f) {
      var cache = {}; // Value cache stored in the closure.

      return function() {
          // Create a string version of the arguments to use as a cache key.
          var key = arguments.length + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,",");
          if (key in cache) return cache[key];
          else return cache[key] = f.apply(this, arguments);
      }
 }

const f = memoize(function(...args) {
  console.log('f was called')
  return args
})

console.log(f(',', ''))
console.log(f('', ','))
```

The second time the function is called with different arguments, so it shouldn't return return the cached value. However, `'f was called'` is logged only once, so it doesn't work as expected.

---

To create a function which would work in all cases, you'd have to store all arguments in cache, and iterate them to check if they are the same. It could be implemented like that:

```js
const memoize = function(f) {
  const cache = []
  return (...args) => {
    for (const element of cache) {
      let hasSameArguments = true
      for (const i of args.keys()) {
        if (args[i] !== element.args[i]) {
          hasSameArguments = false
          break
        }
      }
      if (hasSameArguments) {
        return element.value
      }
    }
    const value = f(...args)
    cache.push({value, args})
    return value
  }
}

const f = memoize(function(...args) {
  console.log('f was called')
  return args
})

console.log(f(',', ''))
console.log(f('', ',')) // different arguments, f is called again

console.log(f(true))
console.log(f(true)) // from cache

const someObj = {}
     ,otherObj = {}

console.log(f(someObj))
console.log(f(someObj)) // the same object, result from cache
console.log(f(otherObj)) // different object, f is called again
console.log(f(otherObj))

console.log(f([1, 2, 3]))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3])) // different object, f is called again
                          // (because [1, 2, 3] !== [1, 2, 3])
```

Note that it compares arguments using `===` operator, so for example if you call the function twice with arrays containing the same values, it wouldn't return the cached result. You can change this behavior by deeply iterating the arguments and checking if all properties are the same.

Comment: Or you could use a Map() to store complex values as keys: https://github.com/thinkloop/memoizerific